# How to Make your Category Titles have H1 tags?

Tags: seo

I´m using the atahualpa theme and have the category titles displayed on the category pages. I want the title to have H1 Tags and the site name and info H3 tags.

Right now, the category titles have H2 tags and the site name and info H1.
(actually, the only place I want them to have H1 tags is on the homepage)

If you are an expert, please help me out.

Comment: It sounds like you are using `<h*>` tags for formatting, and you should not be doing that. They are semantic. They should create a logical outline.

Comment: Well, the category pages should have the category name in H1 tags and the posts in that category in H2. Having the site title in H1 tags on more than the homepage hurts your rankings. Therefore, I want to know how to put the category title in H1 (only on category pages) and the site title in H3.

Answer (score 2):

Try `<h1><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>` in Archives (archive.php) on your theme file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to search the files in your theme. Every author is different. It would depend on how your theme is set up. Most themes do have a category.php file. You need to search through whatever files are in your theme for the_title();

find the title for all the category stuff and I am sure you will see something like this

```
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
```

simply change the h2 to an h1 and you will be good.

Comment: Thank you Jamie, but the header would still have the site title in H1. 

Now of course I could change the header so the site title would only be in H3 on the category pages. But that´s quite a bit complicated for me.

Comment: Normally it would be doable but the atahualpa theme is coded in a complicated manner that I don´t understand.